# Can't recognise or open these custom motorcycle lights

Tags: motorcycle, lights

The previous owner of my Honda Hornet 900 was a brilliant mechanic but a terrible electrician. They added some extra lights that are beautifully fitted but wired illegally. There's a basic switch on the handlebars that turns them on but if you turn them off and immediately on again they switch mode:

1. High beam.
2. Low beam.
3. Flashing.

To make it worse they wired them into the headlamp so they're only on when the headlamp is full beam. That means if I ride at night and change the headlamp from full to low to full then they change mode which makes them illegal (in New Zealand).

I want to get the lights open to see if the control for the modes is in there but I can't figure out how to get it open. Is this a standard part or has it been specially machined? There's no model or serial number on the outside.

More photos [here](https://flic.kr/s/aHskxeoRfd).

[image: Light]

Comment: I think it will be pretty tough finding someone with experience of an off brand chinese light.  Wish I could help.

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine found them on AliExpress as [3000LM Black Transformers 3 Modes U5 Led Motorcycle Headlight Waterproof LED](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sale-Black-Transformers-3000LM-3-Modes-U5-Cree-Led-Motorcycle-Headlight-Waterproof-Lamp-Laser-Light-for/32385774443.html). The 3 mode switching is actually built into the light as a feature. However, I also found this video [How to remove strobe and low beam mode from U5 U3 motorcycle LED fog light](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQIRV1y-Q6E) which I will try.